# How do I prove $|(\mathbb{Q} \setminus \mathbb{N})\cup \mathbb{Z}| = \aleph_0$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I came across with this claim, I hope someone could help me prove it:

$|(\mathbb{Q} \setminus \mathbb{N})\cup \mathbb{Z}| = \aleph_0$

Comment: Umm, $(\mathbb Q\setminus\mathbb N)\cup\mathbb Z=\mathbb Q$.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews I don't understand, what is this?

Comment: and $|\mathbb{Q} | = |\mathbb{N } | = | \mathbb{Z} | = ℵ_{0}$

Comment: @Stephen I know that but how does it help me here?

Comment: If sets are equal their cardinalities are equal..

Comment: @LiziPizi Combine the two hints from Thomas Andrews and Stephen.

Answer (score 2):

- $\mathbb Q$ is the set of all rational numbers.
- $\mathbb N$ is the set of all natural numbers.
- $\mathbb Z$ is the set of all integers.
- $\aleph_0$ is the cardinality of $\mathbb N$.

Actually, $\mathbb N \subset \mathbb Z \subset \mathbb Q$.

Therefore, it is trivial that $(\mathbb Q \setminus \mathbb N) \cup \mathbb Z = \mathbb Q$ (can be easily proved using the definition of subset).

Now, two sets $A$ and $B$ have the **same** cardinality $\iff$ there exists **injective** functions $f:A\to B$ and $g:B\to A$.

Refer to the proof that $\mathbb N$ and $\mathbb Q$ have the same cardinality.